# How to dynamically update my UI

Tags: c#, wpf, task, dynamic-ui

I have looked around at several questions relating dynamic UIs but I still don't understand what I'm missing. In addition, I've followed tutorials on how to use tasks but my understanding is still limited. Here is what I would like to achieve:

My app is doing some work behind the scene but I would like my UI to be responsive. I've tried the following (see code) but the UI doesn't start updating until the dispatcher is invoked. I would like the UI status to be:

1. Creating... -- as soon as the the CreatePivotTableButton is clicked
2. Establishing Connection... -- before calling the provider.GetReportData method
3. Connection Successful or Connection failure depending on the result
4. Done.

   ```
    <!-- language: lang-cs -->
    private void CreatePivotTableButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

       this.StatusToBeDisplayed.Content = "Creating...";
       this.DescriptionLabel.IsEnabled = false;
       this.TextBlockBorder.IsEnabled = true; 

       List<CombinedData> items = (List<CombinedData>)CustomerComboBox.ItemsSource;
       List<int> selectedItems = new List<int>();
       foreach (CombinedData item in items)
       {
           if (item.IsSelected)
           {
               selectedItems.Add(item.ReferenceId);
           }
       }

       PCTProvider provider = new PCTProvider();
       ExportToExcel export = new ExportToExcel();

       ExcelAutomation excelAutomation = new ExcelAutomation();

       this.ResultTextBlock.Text = "Establishing Connection";
       DataTable generateReportDataTable = provider.GetReportData(selectedItems);
       Excel.Workbook workbook = export.ExportDataTableToExcel(generateReportDataTable);
       Task updateTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => excelAutomation.CreatePivotTable(workbook)));
       }).ContinueWith(result =>
       {
           Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.StatusToBeDisplayed.Content = "Done!"));
           Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => OriginalStatus()));
       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

   }
   ```

I highly appreciate your time and help.

Comment: You may want to break up your code into smaller methods that your button event could call. Then, before each method call you'd update your UI to tell the user what's about to happen. These would fire immediately because they happen before the real worker methods are even called.   
  
If you want to keep this all in one method then you could just try using `Application.DoEvents`. This just tells the runtime that it should take a breath and see if anything else is waiting to run (like updating a form).

Comment: Shouldn't the UI update to "creating..." as soon as the button is clicked? I'm going to break it down in little methods and see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Just because it's first inside the method doesn't mean the processor will get a chance to do the actual work involved. That's what the doevents does but it's not good practice any more to use that.  You may want to look into asynchronous coding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @Oliver did you solve the problem?

Comment: @chaddienhart thanks again for your help. It works like a charm. On more question what would I need to do to update the UI. In other words, I'm planning on adding a TextBlock and  I would like to add texts describing what's going on behind the scene. Would I need to use another Dispatcher.Invoke or should I create a new method that takes care of it?
Thanks again

Comment: @Oliver you could use additional `Dispatcher.Invoke` (or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` for asynchronous updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the `ContinueWith` and/or possibly the `TaskScheduler`
By doing the work in a Task you allow the UI thread to be responsive to the message pump.
You might want to move more of the work of your `CreatePivotTableButton` into the Task.

Try this instead:

```
private void CreatePivotTableButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    this.StatusToBeDisplayed.Content = "Creating...";
    this.DescriptionLabel.IsEnabled = false;
    this.TextBlockBorder.IsEnabled = true; 
    // move the rest of the code into your Task to perform the work off the UI thread
    Task updateTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        List<CombinedData> items = (List<CombinedData>)CustomerComboBox.ItemsSource;
        List<int> selectedItems = new List<int>();
        foreach (CombinedData item in items)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(item.ReferenceId);
            }
        }

        PCTProvider provider = new PCTProvider();
        ExportToExcel export = new ExportToExcel();

        ExcelAutomation excelAutomation = new ExcelAutomation();

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.ResultTextBlock.Text = "Establishing Connection"));
        DataTable generateReportDataTable = provider.GetReportData(selectedItems);
        Excel.Workbook workbook = export.ExportDataTableToExcel(generateReportDataTable);

        excelAutomation.CreatePivotTable(workbook);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.StatusToBeDisplayed.Content = "Done!"));
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => OriginalStatus()));
    });
}
```